# How to configure karate to stop execution when any scenario fails?

Tags: karate

What's the best way to configure karate to stop execution when any of the scenario fails?

I saw `karate.abort()` however I think it will just abort that specific scenario.

I want to abort the whole feature file execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported as of now. This has never been requested until now and on the other hand people demand "soft assertions". Feel free to raise a feature request and explain why this is important.

Note that you have the option of running a chosen `Scenario` by name (IntelliJ) or tag from the IDE.

Comment: @pether-thomas I have a test scenario where my API is calling other APIs, I need to first test that whether those are up or not, if they are up then proceed with my API testing. If they are not up then there is no point of proceeding with my API testing as they will fail.

Comment: @ernitingoel just use a JUnit `@BeforeClass` to run a feature via the Java API (search for it in the docs) and you will be good :) personally I think this is not worth the effort. worst case ? you get a lot of failed tests. best case 99% of the time, all is good.